# How to solve the error: Cannot invoke initializer for type `......` with an argument list of type`...`?

Tags: swift, struct, save, codable

I need help with solving the error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'QuotesViewController.RandomItems' with an argument list of type '(items: [String], seen: Int)'

This is my code:

```
struct RandomItems: Codable
{
    var items : [String]
    var seen  = 0

    init(_ items:[String])
    { self.items = items }

    mutating func next() -> String
    {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count - seen)))
        let item  = items.remove(at:index)
        items.append(item)
        seen = (seen + 1) % items.count
        return item
    }
    func toPropertyList() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "items": items,
            "seen": seen
        ]
    }


    }
}

extension QuotesViewController.RandomItems {
    init?(propertyList: [String: Any]) {
        return nil
    }
}

let a = QuotesViewController.RandomItems(items: ["hello"], seen: 2) //<-- Error
let data: Data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(a)
let b = try! JSONDecoder().decode(QuotesViewController.RandomItems.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Well `QuotesViewController.RandomItems` doesn't have an `init(items:seen:)`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
let a = QuotesViewController.RandomItems(items: ["hello"], seen: 2) //<-- Error
```

invokes an initialiser that does not exist. Create one like this:

```
init(items:[String], seen: Int)
{ 
    self.items = items 
    self.seen = seen
}
```

For good measure, change the existing initialiser to

```
init(_ items: [String])
{
    self.init(items: items, seen: 0)
}
```

so that, if you need to add extra stuff to the initialisers, you only need to do it in one place.

Or just have one initialiser

```
init(items:[String], seen: Int = 0)
{ 
    self.items = items 
    self.seen = seen
}
```